# Entry point for java web application

Tags: java

I need to know where i can start a cron in my java web app.  I need this cron to run daily and be rescheduled if the server restarts. Do java web application have hook where i can do this?

----edits----

Im using quartz to schedule a task which will pull down and parse a csv file and store it in a database. I need to know where i should schedule it to run the first time

Comment: What exactly do you need to have done when and why?

Comment: Im using quartz to schedule a task which will pull down and parse a csv file and store it in a database.  I need to know where i should schedule it to run the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to use a [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).  It supports two methods that run when an web app is started and ended. This [article](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-servlet/how-to-work-with-servletcontextlistener-3.html) goes over setting one up.  You can start the Quartz scheduler in the Initialize method and shut it down in the Destroy method.